# How I set a custom font in the UltraWinGrid?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms, infragistics

I'm trying to use a custom TTF font in the UltraWinGrid. I create a PrivateFontCollection instance, and then I have added my font resource to this

```
pfc = New PrivateFontCollection
Dim fonMemPointer As IntPtr = _
    Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(My.Resources.FontAwesome.Length)
Marshal.Copy(My.Resources.FontAwesome, _
             0, _
             fonMemPointer, My.Resources.FontAwesome.Length)

pfc.AddMemoryFont(fonMemPointer, My.Resources.FontAwesome.Length)
```

So, on the Grid I have a CellAppearance Property that It have a FonData Property. This one has a CreateFont Method which I don't know what is for? But I did this:

```
.CellAppearance.FontData.Name = _
                 .CellAppearance.CreateFont(New Font(pfc.Families(0), Single.))
.CellAppearance.FontData.SizeInPoints = 9
.CellAppearance.FontData.Bold = DefaultableBoolean.False
```

This din't work for me. Could you give me any suggestion for this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using CreateFont() method, you could create a Font based on the FontData settings of particular cell, but if you want to apply your custom font, you should use the ultraGrid1.Font. For example:

```
PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
pfc.AddFontFile("..\\..\\customFont.ttf");
ultraGrid1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(pfc.Families[0], 12F);
```

Here is a screenshot of my test with custom font:

[image]